# React - Build the select box with dynamic values

Tags: reactjs, arrays, json, next.js

I am new the React and I am trying to populate the select box with the dynamic object.

**The code:**

```
import React, { useEffect, useState, setState } from "react";
const selectBoxWrapper = () => {
    const [thisdata, setData] = useState([]);
    let selectContent = {};
    useEffect(() => {
        async function selectBoxHandler() {
            const res = await fetch(`api-call`);
            const result = await res.json();
            const selectData = result.data.results.map((items) => {
                if (items.data.labels.results.length) {
                    selectContent = items.data.labels.results.map((itemresults) => (
                        <option key={itemresults.id} value={itemresults.name}>
                            {itemresults.label}
                        </option>
                    ));
                }
            });
            setData(selectContent);
        }
        selectBoxHandler();
    }
    return (
        <div>
            <select>
                {thisdata}
            </select>
        </div>
    );
};
export default selectBoxWrapper;
```

**Result**

```
<option value="abc">abc</option>
```

**Expected Result**

```
<option value="abc">abc</option>
<option value="xyz">xyz</option>
<option value="aaa">aaa</option>
<option value="bbb">bbb</option>
```

**Data when console.log on {itemresults}**

```
{prefix: 'global', name: 'abc', id: '3322', label: 'abc'}
{prefix: 'global', name: 'xyz', id: '234', label: 'xyz'}
{prefix: 'global', name: 'aaa', id: '45455', label: 'aaa'} 
{prefix: 'global', name: 'bbb', id: '7766', label: 'bbb'}
```

Please help me render multiple values

Comment: can you update the question with the result replaced with sample data from API call as someone can recreate the issue and check.

Comment: added data from the console.log

Comment: It will be easier for you if you just save the `itemresults` inside the state and then map through them inside the return function of the component.

Comment: @orbnexus you could answer this yourself since you solved it

Answer (score 1):

```
import React, { useEffect, useState, setState } from "react";
const selectBoxWrapper = () => {
    const [thisdata, setData] = useState([]);


    useEffect(() => {
        (async() => {
            const res = await fetch(`api-call`);
            const result = await res.json();
            setData(result.data.results);       
        })()
    }
    return (
        <div>
            <select>
                {
                 thisdata?.map((item, idx) => (
                       <option key={idx} value={item.name}>
                            {item.label}
                        </option>
                ))}
            </select>
        </div>
    );
};
export default selectBoxWrapper;
```